# Differences between the two generated lists, python

Tags: python, list

I encountered this problem when creating lists. Can someone explain why there is a difference between the two lists?

```
bucket = [ ]

for n in range(5):
    bucket.append([])

lists = [ [ ] ]*(5)
for n in range(5):
    bucket[n].append(n)
    lists[n].append(n)

print bucket
# [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]

print lists
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lists = [ [ ] ] * (5)
```

creates a 5 element list, where each its element is **a reference to the same, empty list**. So once you add anything to "one" of them - you add to all.

while in the same time appending `[]` (like with `bucket` variable) in a loop appends each time new list, so you can add to them independently

Comment: You can also read a detailed explanation of this behavior (and a work around using list comprehension) in [this recent Ned Batchelder's blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201308/names_and_values_making_a_game_board.html).